# How to make a string from a NSDate variable as well as another NSString variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I am playing around with making a unique ID for whenever a button is pushed in my application. I basically want it to be two NSString variables that I make concatenated together.

So far, what I have got it mostly working as it gives me no errors in the code itself, but it does only give me (null) as my text in my label.

Where I have the 2 is basically a placeholder for where I will eventually have a variable that will look up what is in the plist for the username.

My code for this is:

```
NSString *UserID;
NSDate *TimeNow;
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmm"];
UserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"",'Username'];
NSString *CurrentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:TimeNow];
SessionID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", UserID, CurrentTime];
UniqueSessionID.text = SessionID;
```

Comment: you have to do the NSDate *TimeNow = [NSDate date];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialised `TimeNow`. And your `UserID` is just being set to the empty string. To clean up that code, I would do this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmm"];
NSString *CurrentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *SessionID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username %@", CurrentTime];
UniqueSessionID.text = SessionID;
```

**Update:**

To have `"Username"` dynamic just do this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmm"];
NSString *CurrentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *UserID = @"Some user";
NSString *SessionID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", UserID, CurrentTime];
UniqueSessionID.text = SessionID;
```

Then just change `UserID` to what you want the username to be.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! It works perfectly. One thing though that I must ask. You have "Username %@", CurrentTime, what if I want to show a dynamic username stored in a variable UserID?

Comment: See my update - I added so you have `UserID` again. Just change that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there should be:

```
NSDate *TimeNow = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: You missed that also `UserID` is the empty string.

Comment: Ya, but this is not that important as this is just a constant value. It should be [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username"]...

Comment: Umm, not even that. How about just `@"Username"`? Also, it does matter as that's why it's saying `" (null)"` rather than `"Username xxx"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm"];//this is the date format of dateFromString
NSString *CurrentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:TimeNow];
[dateFromString release]; 
UserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"",'Username'];
SessionID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", UserID, CurrentTime];
UniqueSessionID.text = SessionID;
```

Comment: You missed that `UserID` is still the empty string.